# Knockout js Keep Show/hide of an element after second bind

Tags: knockout.js

I have the follow  code in knockout.js 
and with javascript when click The div element i hide it.
but in second bind after ajax request the div is show again.

```
<div id="myrootDiv">
    <!-- ko foreach: Items -->
    <div class="myclass" data-bind="html: myData"></div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

javascript code

```
$("#myrootDiv").on("click",".myclass",function (){
$(this).toggle(); 
});
```

How i will make it to remember the visibility on each binding?
when i call

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonData,{}, myVM);
```

all div elements are show again.How can keep them not visible depence of user selection.
and here is my View code

```
    var ViewModel = function() {};
    var myVM = new ViewModel('myrootDiv');

var tempjson={"items":[{"id":"1","myData":"test data1"},{"id":"2","myData":"test data2"},{"id":"3","myData":"test data3"}]};

    var jsonData =$.parseJSON(tempjson);
    ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonData,{}, myVM);
    ko.applyBindings(myVM,document.getElementById('myrootDiv'));
```

and on ajax success i do

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonData,{}, myVM);
```

Answer (score 1):

not quite sure what you mean by the second bind, but usually what you are after can be achieved by adding a `isVisible = ko.observable(true);` to the individual items in the Items array and then in the html have something line the following.

```
<!-- ko foreach: Items -->
<div data-bind="html: myData, visible: isVisible">
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

The isVisibile property keeps track of if the item is visible or not.  Elseewhere in your code you could turn the visibility on or off as you require for each item.

Comment: i have updated my code here is a sample json.How i will add the isVisible on my view and on each ajax request to show only the elements user have clicked?thanks